# How can I load an existing pptx file with PptxGenJs

Tags: javascript, pptxgenjs

how can I load an existing pptx file? Our customers would like to create a master pptx file with their own coporate branding. They are users and not developers. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Holm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with PptxGenJS, as you can see it is listed as a feature they will not be implementing:

https://github.com/gitbrent/PptxGenJS/wiki/Unimplemented-Features

If your data does not have to be in pptx format, then you can reproduce an HTML table and use it within PptxGenJS:

https://gitbrent.github.io/PptxGenJS/docs/html-to-powerpoint.html

Comment: Thanks for the links, especially for the first one. I didn't find then. Thanks again.

Comment: If you feel that answered your question, please mark it as answered. Thanks